# Aurora:Find diff between two tables based on primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I have TABLE1 like below

```
|001000900|aaaaa BELLOWS CORPORATION||N|
|001000905|ddddd DEPARTMENT OF LABOR AND EMPLOYMENT SECURITY|BUREAU OF COMPLIANCE|N|
|001001049|gggg RAVIOLI MFG CO INC|SPINELLI BKY RAVIOLI PASTRY SP|N|
|001001130|dddd ANGELES UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT|TRANSPORTATION BRANCH|N|
|001001143|ffff MUSIC PARTIES, INC||N|
|001001155|BOSTON BRASS AND IRON CO||N|
|001001171|HANCOCK MARINE, INC.||N|
|001001184|TRILLION CORPORATION||N|
|001001192|HAWAII STATE CHIROPRACTIC ASSOCIATION INC||N|
|001001379|THE FRUIT SQUARE PEOPLE INC|L & M BAKERY|N|
|001001416|J & S MARKET||N|
```

And Table2 like this

```
|001000145|PARADISE TAN||N|
|001000306|SHRUT & ASCH LEATHER COMPANY, INC.||N|
|001000355|HARRISON SPECIALTY CO., INC.||N|
|001000363|LOUIS M. GERSON CO., INC.||N|
|001000467|SAVE THE SEA TURTLES INTERNATIONAL|ADOPT THE BEACH HI|N|
|001000504|DIRIGO SPICE CORPORATION|CUNNINGHAM SPICE|N|
|001000744|FREEDMAN THREAD COMPANY|COLONIAL THREAD CO|N|
|001000756|AFFORDABLE AIR CONDITIONING|P R ENTERPRISE|N|
|001000900|CLIFLEX BELLOWS CORPORATION||N|
|001000905|FLORIDA DEPARTMENT OF LABOR AND EMPLOYMENT SECURITY|BUREAU OF COMPLIANCE|N|
|001001049|SPINELLI RAVIOLI MFG CO INC|SPINELLI BKY RAVIOLI PASTRY SP|N|
|001001130|LOS ANGELES UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT|TRANSPORTATION BRANCH|N|
|001001143|TOSCO MUSIC PARTIES, INC||N|
|001001155|BOSTON BRASS AND IRON CO||N|
```

My requirement is to find the rows which is present in both tables (Matching rows)  based on primary key which is first column only if their others columns are changed.

For example if primary key is same and their other columns are different at least one then that will come in output .

How can i do this .
Plain except will give me result ?

Comment: What would be expected output as per the given sample data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a `join` with a `where` condition?

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pk = t2.pk
where not (t1.col2 <=> t2.col2) or
      not (t1.col3 <=> t2.col3) or
      not (t1.col4 <=> t2.col4) ;
```

Comment: yes ..But i have 129 columns so do i have to put condition for each columns ?

Comment: @Shailendra . . . Yes, I think so.